# Convert string variable containing timestamp to timestamp with time zone

Tags: timestamp

i'm using `insert into tablename values((to_char(cast('Wed Feb 15 2017 14:00' as timestamptz), 'HH:MI PM')::timetz) AS the_time);`

I want to convert it into timestamp with time zone.
but

> 'Wed Feb 15 2017 14:00'

is stored in my character varying variable.
When i use `(to_char(cast(string_variable as timestamptz), 'HH:MI PM')::timetz)` AS the_time instead of `(to_char(cast('Wed Feb 15 2017 14:00' as timestamptz), 'HH:MI PM')::timetz) AS the_time;`

I get an error as my location where this value is to be inserted is of type timestamp with time zone.

I hope its not complicated.
Thank You.

Comment: Hi, what programming language are you using, can you provide some code?

Comment: i'm getting issue at backend.

Comment: OK, can you please provide your JS code then?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checklist_data_insert1(checklist_time character varying) 
RETURNS character varying AS
$B$
DECLARE
 temp charcater varying;
BEGIN

 insert into check_list_ut(time_of_day) values (to_char(cast('Wed Feb 15 2017 14:00' as timestamptz), 'HH:MI PM')::timestamptz) AS the_time);

RETURN 'ok'; 
 
END;
$B$
language plpgsql;

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "02:00 PM"
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "02:00 PM"
SQL state: 22007

Comment: I'm unable to format correct code here...
new to this....
Sorry...

Comment: I've got This sorted out... thank you @Jaay